# How to ftp or download a file using a url in linux console without using browser?

Tags: linux, ftp

How do I ftp or download the following in linux console without using browser?

ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/u-boot/u-boot-2011.12.tar.bz2

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `wget` to download files from HTTP and FTP from the command line:

```
wget ftp://ftp.denx.de/pub/u-boot/u-boot-2011.12.tar.bz2
```

This will create a file named `u-boot-2011.12.tar.bz2` in the current directory.